# Getting Unknown provider: $routeProvider with ngRoute included

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have upgraded from Angular.JS 1.1.5 to 1.2.26 and now im geting

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
```

Here is my **index.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="app">
        <header ng-include="'partials/menu.html'"></header>
        <div id="body">
            <ng-view></ng-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my **app.js**:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
            when('/tasks', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/tasks.html',
                controller: 'tasksCtrl'
            }).
            when('/goals', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/goals.html',
                controller: 'goalsCtrl'
            }).
            when('/notes', {
                templateUrl: 'partials/notes.html',
                controller: 'notesCtrl'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/"
            });
        }
    ]);
```

I also tried Angular and Angular-route versions 1.2.6, 1.2.9, 1.3.0 but same issue.

I need Angular features that are only 1.2.0+, so downgrading is not an option.

Comment: Your error cannot be reproduced. please make a plunker.

Comment: same as @IlanFrumer, couldn't replicate the issue